# Cron job error in php

Tags: php, cron

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MY Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        $dbcon=mysql_connect("localhost","santu_dbuser","santulan@123") or die("mysql connection error".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("santu_db",$dbcon) or die("mysql database error".mysql_error());
        $qry="SELECT DISTINCT CaseId,eemp_id, MAX(FeedbackDate) from session_feedback_master WHERE added_by like 'USER' GROUP BY CaseId";
        $result=mysql_query($qry) or die("mysql query error".mysql_error());

ini_set("SMTP","localhost");

ini_set("smtp_port","25");

ini_set('sendmail_from', 'no.reply@santulan.co.in');

        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($num>0)
        {       
?>
        <table border="1px">    
        <tr>
            <td>Case Id</td>
               <td>Feedback Date</td>
            <td>Emp Id</td>
            <td>Email</td>  
        </tr>
    <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$row["CaseId"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["MAX(FeedbackDate)"]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row["eemp_id"]."</td>";         
             echo "</tr>";
        <!--- for calculation--->

        $mydate=new DateTime($row["MAX(FeedbackDate)"]);
        $eemp_id=$row["eemp_id"];               
        echo $eemp_id;  
        $now=new DateTime('today');
        echo "Diffrence in days";
        echo $datediff =  $now->diff($mydate)->d;
        //echo "<br>";      
        if($datediff>10)
        {
        echo "we are checking"; 
        $eemp_id=$row["eemp_id"];       
            $qry="SELECT email FROM  end_employee_master where id=".$eemp_id ;
            $result1=mysql_query($qry) or die("mysql query error".mysql_error());
            $num=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            echo $num;
            if($result1)
            {

                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                {
                    $eemp_id=$row["eemp_id"];

                echo "employee id is". $eemp_id;    
                echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
                  //echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
                 //$id=$row["id"];

                $to = $row[0];
                echo   " we found mail id".$to;
                $subject = "This is subject";
                $message = "This is simple text message from santulan regarding you have not "
                ."replied for the E-counseling chat for last 28 days ";
                $from = "no.reply@santulan.co.in";
                $header = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                $retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
                if( $retval == true )  
                {
                echo "result found";
                echo "Message sent successfully from live.... $mail";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "Message could not be sent...";
                }
                     echo "</tr>";
                echo "no of rows: $num";
              echo "Mail is: $mail";

                }           
            }
        else
        {
        echo " no record found";    
        }               
        }
        else
        {           
        echo "Date difference not greater ";
        }
        }
        }
    ?>      
        </table>`enter code here`   
</body>
```

When I put this file at cron and I set my mail id for alerts, I get the following maul errors:

> /home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' /home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php: line 1:`'

The file runs absolutely right when I run it manually.It looks like there are mostly some html error but I cant get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does depend a little on how your cron job is setup however normally..

You cant run a cron job with the following at the top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MY Database</title>
</head>
<body>
```

you need

```
#! /usr/bin/php
```

(replacing the path to php as required)

Otherwise unix doesnt recognise it as a viable script and what to run it with - it doesnt care it says .php at the end

You do need also to remember that cron may not have picked up all the environment variables you have when you run it from the command line.

so even if you run it as /usr/bin/php myfile.php

it may not work the same, as commands may not be in your path that you had before.

Also - its outputting html because you have coded html in it. If you arent going to be running this file from your website ever - then dont code it to do so. You can get it to output better plain text which normally is emailed to you on any output.

Comment: i have given my path as like this sir  /home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php,is it the correct way to give the path to a cron job file

Comment: Like how? I mention 2 things in this post.  did you write the code on a PC and upload it?

Comment: yes sir i write the code in pc and uploaded it,the path i have given to run the file is     /home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php

Comment: right so you need to change the file as explained above - and also check that file doesnt still have PC line feeds in it.

Comment: Hello,now it gives me this error                                                                                          /home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"localhost","santu_dbuser","santulan@123"'
/home/santu/public_html/cron_job.php: line 2: `         $dbcon=mysql_connect("localhost","santu_dbuser","santulan@123") or die("mysql connection error".mysql_error());'

Comment: please help me i am tired of this cron